# I cant retrieve the text in global variables

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, global-variables, tk-toolkit

The user has entered a username and password in one method of a class and i'm trying to retrieve those inputs in another method of a class but the when i print out the "These are you details bit the username and password are just blank please help. This is the code,(not all of it)
Thanks in advance

```
 from tkinter import *
import time
import tkinter as tk
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, LoginPage):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        #for frame in self.frames.values():
            #frame.grid_remove()

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry("1024x720")

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=" Page 2", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        global username
        global password

        username = StringVar()
        password = StringVar()
        name = StringVar()
        email = StringVar()
        Label(self, text="Please enter details below").pack()
        Label(self, text="").pack()
        Label(self, text="username").pack()
        usernameentry = Entry(self, textvariable=username)
        usernameentry.pack()
        Label(self, text="").pack()
        Label(self, text="password").pack()
        password = Entry(self, textvariable=password)
        password.pack()
        Button(self, text="Register", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(LoginPage)).pack()

        # usernameentry.delete(0, END)
        # passwordnameentry.delete(0, END)

class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=" Page 1", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        userr = username.get()
        passrr = password.get()

        Label(self, text=(
                "These are you're details \nUsername: " + userr + "\nPassword: " + passrr)).pack()
        Button(self, text="Confirm Registration").pack()
        Button(self, text="Edit Registration").pack()

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

also im quite new to tktinter and oop so please for any solutions, i ask if you could please explain it for me in a way i would understand, thankyou for your help in advanced.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: We cannot help you with your question as it is. Please follow Bryan's advice and create a MRE. If we can run your code locally and reproduce the error, it will be easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking, that you make a mistake here:

```
Button(self, text="Register", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DetailsPage)).pack()
```

You probably switch between frames like this guy:
https://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/

So  you create dict of frames like above guy with link.  You create these frames by calling constructor (`__init__()`), so you initialize userr and passrr with global variables username and password, which are blank . You make it only one time, during creates dictionary of frames. When  you press button Register  you call method show_frame() -this method probably look like this:

```
def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()
```

of course you refresh global variables but you don't call constructor of DetailsPage,which change label text. You are only switching frame!  So your user and password are still blank.

Solution:
create method to refresh your label in class DetailsPage:

```
class DetailsPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        '''Your  code,  remove userr, passrr and Label '''
        self.label=Label(self).pack()
    def initUserData():
        userr = username.get()
        passrr = password.get()
        self.label['text']="These are you're details \nUsername: " + userr + "\nPassword: " + passrr))
```

method show_frame() for DetailsPage:

```
def show_DetailsPage(self):
    self.frames[DetailsPage].initUserData()
    frame[DetailsPage].tkraise()
```

It probably should help.